# New-AzureRmADApplication equivalent of New-AzureADApplication -RequiredResourceAccess

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am able to set the azure application ("Read Directory Data") permissions using  the below but how can I set the same using New-AzureRmADApplication.

```
$appPermission1 = New-Object -TypeName 
   "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "5778995a-e1bf- 
   45b8-affa-663a9f3f4d04","Role" #Read Directory data

$reqGraph.ResourceAccess = $appPermission1

$myApp = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $applicationName -IdentifierUris 
    $applicationURI -Homepage $appHomePageUrl -ReplyUrls $appReplyURLs -ErrorUrl 
    $applicationURI -LogoutUrl $applicationURI  -PasswordCredentials 
    $PasswordCredential -RequiredResourceAccess $reqGraph
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you could not do that with `New-AzureRmADApplication`.

`New-AzureRmADApplication` belongs to [Azure RM powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azurermps-6.8.1&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-6.4.0).
`New-AzureADApplication` belongs to [Azure AD powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0).

They are different, not all the things AD module can do that RM module also can. You could find all the command and their properties related to ad in RM module, check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/?view=azurermps-6.8.1#active_directory). There is no property like `RequiredResourceAccess`.

Comment: That's the issue the new call does not acept -RequiredResourceAccess parameter  at this point of time

Comment: @Nataraj Sure, if the RM module can do all the things like the same of AD module, it is unnecessary for AD module to be existing, right?

Comment: Here is what you would have to do if you are a customer or an end user if you would want to automate and end to end work flow then you have to figure out If you would want to use AzureAD or RM Modules , and i ended up in a situation where i had to go back and fourth with these modules.